# Cursor highlights row of text when clicking on the left side of Word doc

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm not sure what I did to cause this, but my cursor in Word now points up and to the right, rather than to the left, and whenever I move the cursor to the left of the Word page.  When the cursor is to the left of the Word doc and I click, it highlights the entire row of text.  When the cursor is to the right of the Word doc, the cursor looks like the capital "I" shape and when I click it simply moves the cursor to the far right side of the line of text.

I believe this functionality is called "Highlight Current Line" cursor and I would like to know how to turn it off so that when my cursor is to the left of the Word page, it points up and to the left and does not highlight a row of text when I click?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Chris, this is default action in Word. When you click to the left of a line, it is selected. Double-click for the paragraph. *I believe this has been how Word works for more than 20 years, since Word 97.* **What is it you want to happen instead?** In recent Ribbon versions, since text was selected, it also pops up the contextual Mini Toolbar.

Comment: If you want, you can look at this WordTips page from 2012 which describes the same behavior. http://web.archive.org/web/20120229082704/http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010511_Selecting_an_Entire_Paragraph.html  -- *using Web Archive*

Answer (score 0):

Does this behavior affect only new documents?

It is a common feature that when you move your mouse to the left, past the left margin, the cursor flips to the right and a click selects the entire row. (Probably the opposite on right-to-left writing).

In your case it appears that you have defined a very large left margin and made it the default.
To fix, adjust the margins and click "default".

I hope this helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the width of the margin. This is how Word works. See comments above.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I said it is a common feature, but the author said it's happening **now** (suggesting it has changed). My answer is based in the fact that **"the cursor looks like the capital "I" shape and when I click it simply moves the cursor to the far right side of the line"**. I have not considered Chris just aligned right, though.

Comment: The I-Beam cursor is the normal mouse pointer when over editable text and in the *right* margin. When the mouse is moved to the left of text, it switches to an arrow pointing up and to the right. Nothing has changed. If you have the I-Beam in the right margin and click, it changes to an arrow pointed up and to the left and places the insertion point/selection at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I know this behavior, I'm not saying Word's basic functionality changed. I'm saying Chris perceived Word's behavior changed which can be caused by configuration changes. But I also assumed that when "the cursor to the far right side of the line", Chris was referring to an empty line. It may be wrong but just wanted to share a possible condition to this behavior.